# How to get the id, currencyname from this kind of api response using angular interface

Tags: javascript, angular, api, object, angular-httpclient

the initial look

when I open on results

How will I get the id, currency name to display it to the UI

Sample response:

```
{
  "results": {
    "ALL": {
      "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
      "currencySymbol": "Lek",
      "id": "ALL"
    },
    "XCD": {
      "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "XCD"
    },
    "EUR": {
      "currencyName": "Euro",
      "currencySymbol": "€",
      "id": "EUR"
    },
    "BBD": {
      "currencyName": "Barbadian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "BBD"
    },
    "BTN": {
      "currencyName": "Bhutanese Ngultrum",
      "id": "BTN"
    },
    "BND": {
      "currencyName": "Brunei Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "BND"
    },
    "XAF": {
      "currencyName": "Central African CFA Franc",
      "id": "XAF"
    },
    "CUP": {
      "currencyName": "Cuban Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "CUP"
    },
    "USD": {
      "currencyName": "United States Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "USD"
    },
    "FKP": {
      "currencyName": "Falkland Islands Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "FKP"
    },
    "GIP": {
      "currencyName": "Gibraltar Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "GIP"
    },
    "HUF": {
      "currencyName": "Hungarian Forint",
      "currencySymbol": "Ft",
      "id": "HUF"
    },
    "IRR": {
      "currencyName": "Iranian Rial",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "IRR"
    },
    "JMD": {
      "currencyName": "Jamaican Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "J$",
      "id": "JMD"
    },
    "AUD": {
      "currencyName": "Australian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "AUD"
    },
    "LAK": {
      "currencyName": "Lao Kip",
      "currencySymbol": "₭",
      "id": "LAK"
    },
    "LYD": {
      "currencyName": "Libyan Dinar",
      "id": "LYD"
    },
    "MKD": {
      "currencyName": "Macedonian Denar",
      "currencySymbol": "ден",
      "id": "MKD"
    },
    "XOF": {
      "currencyName": "West African CFA Franc",
      "id": "XOF"
    },
    "NZD": {
      "currencyName": "New Zealand Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "NZD"
    },
    "OMR": {
      "currencyName": "Omani Rial",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "OMR"
    },
    "PGK": {
      "currencyName": "Papua New Guinean Kina",
      "id": "PGK"
    },
    "RWF": {
      "currencyName": "Rwandan Franc",
      "id": "RWF"
    },
    "WST": {
      "currencyName": "Samoan Tala",
      "id": "WST"
    },
    "RSD": {
      "currencyName": "Serbian Dinar",
      "currencySymbol": "Дин.",
      "id": "RSD"
    },
    "SEK": {
      "currencyName": "Swedish Krona",
      "currencySymbol": "kr",
      "id": "SEK"
    },
    "TZS": {
      "currencyName": "Tanzanian Shilling",
      "currencySymbol": "TSh",
      "id": "TZS"
    },
    "AMD": {
      "currencyName": "Armenian Dram",
      "id": "AMD"
    },
    "BSD": {
      "currencyName": "Bahamian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "BSD"
    },
    "BAM": {
      "currencyName": "Bosnia And Herzegovina Konvertibilna Marka",
      "currencySymbol": "KM",
      "id": "BAM"
    },
    "CVE": {
      "currencyName": "Cape Verdean Escudo",
      "id": "CVE"
    },
    "CNY": {
      "currencyName": "Chinese Yuan",
      "currencySymbol": "¥",
      "id": "CNY"
    },
    "CRC": {
      "currencyName": "Costa Rican Colon",
      "currencySymbol": "₡",
      "id": "CRC"
    },
    "CZK": {
      "currencyName": "Czech Koruna",
      "currencySymbol": "Kč",
      "id": "CZK"
    },
    "ERN": {
      "currencyName": "Eritrean Nakfa",
      "id": "ERN"
    },
    "GEL": {
      "currencyName": "Georgian Lari",
      "id": "GEL"
    },
    "HTG": {
      "currencyName": "Haitian Gourde",
      "id": "HTG"
    },
    "INR": {
      "currencyName": "Indian Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₹",
      "id": "INR"
    },
    "JOD": {
      "currencyName": "Jordanian Dinar",
      "id": "JOD"
    },
    "KRW": {
      "currencyName": "South Korean Won",
      "currencySymbol": "₩",
      "id": "KRW"
    },
    "LBP": {
      "currencyName": "Lebanese Lira",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "LBP"
    },
    "MWK": {
      "currencyName": "Malawian Kwacha",
      "id": "MWK"
    },
    "MRO": {
      "currencyName": "Mauritanian Ouguiya",
      "id": "MRO"
    },
    "MZN": {
      "currencyName": "Mozambican Metical",
      "id": "MZN"
    },
    "ANG": {
      "currencyName": "Netherlands Antillean Gulden",
      "currencySymbol": "ƒ",
      "id": "ANG"
    },
    "PEN": {
      "currencyName": "Peruvian Nuevo Sol",
      "currencySymbol": "S/.",
      "id": "PEN"
    },
    "QAR": {
      "currencyName": "Qatari Riyal",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "QAR"
    },
    "STD": {
      "currencyName": "Sao Tome And Principe Dobra",
      "id": "STD"
    },
    "SLL": {
      "currencyName": "Sierra Leonean Leone",
      "id": "SLL"
    },
    "SOS": {
      "currencyName": "Somali Shilling",
      "currencySymbol": "S",
      "id": "SOS"
    },
    "SDG": {
      "currencyName": "Sudanese Pound",
      "id": "SDG"
    },
    "SYP": {
      "currencyName": "Syrian Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "SYP"
    },
    "AOA": {
      "currencyName": "Angolan Kwanza",
      "id": "AOA"
    },
    "AWG": {
      "currencyName": "Aruban Florin",
      "currencySymbol": "ƒ",
      "id": "AWG"
    },
    "BHD": {
      "currencyName": "Bahraini Dinar",
      "id": "BHD"
    },
    "BZD": {
      "currencyName": "Belize Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "BZ$",
      "id": "BZD"
    },
    "BWP": {
      "currencyName": "Botswana Pula",
      "currencySymbol": "P",
      "id": "BWP"
    },
    "BIF": {
      "currencyName": "Burundi Franc",
      "id": "BIF"
    },
    "KYD": {
      "currencyName": "Cayman Islands Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "KYD"
    },
    "COP": {
      "currencyName": "Colombian Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "COP"
    },
    "DKK": {
      "currencyName": "Danish Krone",
      "currencySymbol": "kr",
      "id": "DKK"
    },
    "GTQ": {
      "currencyName": "Guatemalan Quetzal",
      "currencySymbol": "Q",
      "id": "GTQ"
    },
    "HNL": {
      "currencyName": "Honduran Lempira",
      "currencySymbol": "L",
      "id": "HNL"
    },
    "IDR": {
      "currencyName": "Indonesian Rupiah",
      "currencySymbol": "Rp",
      "id": "IDR"
    },
    "ILS": {
      "currencyName": "Israeli New Sheqel",
      "currencySymbol": "₪",
      "id": "ILS"
    },
    "KZT": {
      "currencyName": "Kazakhstani Tenge",
      "currencySymbol": "лв",
      "id": "KZT"
    },
    "KWD": {
      "currencyName": "Kuwaiti Dinar",
      "id": "KWD"
    },
    "LSL": {
      "currencyName": "Lesotho Loti",
      "id": "LSL"
    },
    "MYR": {
      "currencyName": "Malaysian Ringgit",
      "currencySymbol": "RM",
      "id": "MYR"
    },
    "MUR": {
      "currencyName": "Mauritian Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "MUR"
    },
    "MNT": {
      "currencyName": "Mongolian Tugrik",
      "currencySymbol": "₮",
      "id": "MNT"
    },
    "MMK": {
      "currencyName": "Myanma Kyat",
      "id": "MMK"
    },
    "NGN": {
      "currencyName": "Nigerian Naira",
      "currencySymbol": "₦",
      "id": "NGN"
    },
    "PAB": {
      "currencyName": "Panamanian Balboa",
      "currencySymbol": "B/.",
      "id": "PAB"
    },
    "PHP": {
      "currencyName": "Philippine Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "₱",
      "id": "PHP"
    },
    "RON": {
      "currencyName": "Romanian Leu",
      "currencySymbol": "lei",
      "id": "RON"
    },
    "SAR": {
      "currencyName": "Saudi Riyal",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "SAR"
    },
    "SGD": {
      "currencyName": "Singapore Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "SGD"
    },
    "ZAR": {
      "currencyName": "South African Rand",
      "currencySymbol": "R",
      "id": "ZAR"
    },
    "SRD": {
      "currencyName": "Surinamese Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "SRD"
    },
    "TWD": {
      "currencyName": "New Taiwan Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "NT$",
      "id": "TWD"
    },
    "TOP": {
      "currencyName": "Paanga",
      "id": "TOP"
    },
    "VEF": {
      "currencyName": "Venezuelan Bolivar",
      "id": "VEF"
    },
    "DZD": {
      "currencyName": "Algerian Dinar",
      "id": "DZD"
    },
    "ARS": {
      "currencyName": "Argentine Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "ARS"
    },
    "AZN": {
      "currencyName": "Azerbaijani Manat",
      "currencySymbol": "ман",
      "id": "AZN"
    },
    "BYR": {
      "currencyName": "Belarusian Ruble",
      "currencySymbol": "p.",
      "id": "BYR"
    },
    "BOB": {
      "currencyName": "Bolivian Boliviano",
      "currencySymbol": "$b",
      "id": "BOB"
    },
    "BGN": {
      "currencyName": "Bulgarian Lev",
      "currencySymbol": "лв",
      "id": "BGN"
    },
    "CAD": {
      "currencyName": "Canadian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "CAD"
    },
    "CLP": {
      "currencyName": "Chilean Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "CLP"
    },
    "CDF": {
      "currencyName": "Congolese Franc",
      "id": "CDF"
    },
    "DOP": {
      "currencyName": "Dominican Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "RD$",
      "id": "DOP"
    },
    "FJD": {
      "currencyName": "Fijian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "FJD"
    },
    "GMD": {
      "currencyName": "Gambian Dalasi",
      "id": "GMD"
    },
    "GYD": {
      "currencyName": "Guyanese Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "GYD"
    },
    "ISK": {
      "currencyName": "Icelandic Króna",
      "currencySymbol": "kr",
      "id": "ISK"
    },
    "IQD": {
      "currencyName": "Iraqi Dinar",
      "id": "IQD"
    },
    "JPY": {
      "currencyName": "Japanese Yen",
      "currencySymbol": "¥",
      "id": "JPY"
    },
    "KPW": {
      "currencyName": "North Korean Won",
      "currencySymbol": "₩",
      "id": "KPW"
    },
    "LVL": {
      "currencyName": "Latvian Lats",
      "currencySymbol": "Ls",
      "id": "LVL"
    },
    "CHF": {
      "currencyName": "Swiss Franc",
      "currencySymbol": "Fr.",
      "id": "CHF"
    },
    "MGA": {
      "currencyName": "Malagasy Ariary",
      "id": "MGA"
    },
    "MDL": {
      "currencyName": "Moldovan Leu",
      "id": "MDL"
    },
    "MAD": {
      "currencyName": "Moroccan Dirham",
      "id": "MAD"
    },
    "NPR": {
      "currencyName": "Nepalese Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "NPR"
    },
    "NIO": {
      "currencyName": "Nicaraguan Cordoba",
      "currencySymbol": "C$",
      "id": "NIO"
    },
    "PKR": {
      "currencyName": "Pakistani Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "PKR"
    },
    "PYG": {
      "currencyName": "Paraguayan Guarani",
      "currencySymbol": "Gs",
      "id": "PYG"
    },
    "SHP": {
      "currencyName": "Saint Helena Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "SHP"
    },
    "SCR": {
      "currencyName": "Seychellois Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "SCR"
    },
    "SBD": {
      "currencyName": "Solomon Islands Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "SBD"
    },
    "LKR": {
      "currencyName": "Sri Lankan Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "LKR"
    },
    "THB": {
      "currencyName": "Thai Baht",
      "currencySymbol": "฿",
      "id": "THB"
    },
    "TRY": {
      "currencyName": "Turkish New Lira",
      "id": "TRY"
    },
    "AED": {
      "currencyName": "UAE Dirham",
      "id": "AED"
    },
    "VUV": {
      "currencyName": "Vanuatu Vatu",
      "id": "VUV"
    },
    "YER": {
      "currencyName": "Yemeni Rial",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "YER"
    },
    "AFN": {
      "currencyName": "Afghan Afghani",
      "currencySymbol": "؋",
      "id": "AFN"
    },
    "BDT": {
      "currencyName": "Bangladeshi Taka",
      "id": "BDT"
    },
    "BRL": {
      "currencyName": "Brazilian Real",
      "currencySymbol": "R$",
      "id": "BRL"
    },
    "KHR": {
      "currencyName": "Cambodian Riel",
      "currencySymbol": "៛",
      "id": "KHR"
    },
    "KMF": {
      "currencyName": "Comorian Franc",
      "id": "KMF"
    },
    "HRK": {
      "currencyName": "Croatian Kuna",
      "currencySymbol": "kn",
      "id": "HRK"
    },
    "DJF": {
      "currencyName": "Djiboutian Franc",
      "id": "DJF"
    },
    "EGP": {
      "currencyName": "Egyptian Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "EGP"
    },
    "ETB": {
      "currencyName": "Ethiopian Birr",
      "id": "ETB"
    },
    "XPF": {
      "currencyName": "CFP Franc",
      "id": "XPF"
    },
    "GHS": {
      "currencyName": "Ghanaian Cedi",
      "id": "GHS"
    },
    "GNF": {
      "currencyName": "Guinean Franc",
      "id": "GNF"
    },
    "HKD": {
      "currencyName": "Hong Kong Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "HKD"
    },
    "XDR": {
      "currencyName": "Special Drawing Rights",
      "id": "XDR"
    },
    "KES": {
      "currencyName": "Kenyan Shilling",
      "currencySymbol": "KSh",
      "id": "KES"
    },
    "KGS": {
      "currencyName": "Kyrgyzstani Som",
      "currencySymbol": "лв",
      "id": "KGS"
    },
    "LRD": {
      "currencyName": "Liberian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "LRD"
    },
    "MOP": {
      "currencyName": "Macanese Pataca",
      "id": "MOP"
    },
    "MVR": {
      "currencyName": "Maldivian Rufiyaa",
      "id": "MVR"
    },
    "MXN": {
      "currencyName": "Mexican Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "MXN"
    },
    "NAD": {
      "currencyName": "Namibian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "NAD"
    },
    "NOK": {
      "currencyName": "Norwegian Krone",
      "currencySymbol": "kr",
      "id": "NOK"
    },
    "PLN": {
      "currencyName": "Polish Zloty",
      "currencySymbol": "zł",
      "id": "PLN"
    },
    "RUB": {
      "currencyName": "Russian Ruble",
      "currencySymbol": "руб",
      "id": "RUB"
    },
    "SZL": {
      "currencyName": "Swazi Lilangeni",
      "id": "SZL"
    },
    "TJS": {
      "currencyName": "Tajikistani Somoni",
      "id": "TJS"
    },
    "TTD": {
      "currencyName": "Trinidad and Tobago Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "TT$",
      "id": "TTD"
    },
    "UGX": {
      "currencyName": "Ugandan Shilling",
      "currencySymbol": "USh",
      "id": "UGX"
    },
    "UYU": {
      "currencyName": "Uruguayan Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$U",
      "id": "UYU"
    },
    "VND": {
      "currencyName": "Vietnamese Dong",
      "currencySymbol": "₫",
      "id": "VND"
    },
    "TND": {
      "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar",
      "id": "TND"
    },
    "UAH": {
      "currencyName": "Ukrainian Hryvnia",
      "currencySymbol": "₴",
      "id": "UAH"
    },
    "UZS": {
      "currencyName": "Uzbekistani Som",
      "currencySymbol": "лв",
      "id": "UZS"
    },
    "TMT": {
      "currencyName": "Turkmenistan Manat",
      "id": "TMT"
    },
    "GBP": {
      "currencyName": "British Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "GBP"
    },
    "ZMW": {
      "currencyName": "Zambian Kwacha",
      "id": "ZMW"
    },
    "BTC": {
      "currencyName": "Bitcoin",
      "currencySymbol": "BTC",
      "id": "BTC"
    },
    "BYN": {
      "currencyName": "New Belarusian Ruble",
      "currencySymbol": "p.",
      "id": "BYN"
    },
    "BMD": {
      "currencyName": "Bermudan Dollar",
      "id": "BMD"
    },
    "GGP": {
      "currencyName": "Guernsey Pound",
      "id": "GGP"
    },
    "CLF": {
      "currencyName": "Chilean Unit Of Account",
      "id": "CLF"
    },
    "CUC": {
      "currencyName": "Cuban Convertible Peso",
      "id": "CUC"
    },
    "IMP": {
      "currencyName": "Manx pound",
      "id": "IMP"
    },
    "JEP": {
      "currencyName": "Jersey Pound",
      "id": "JEP"
    },
    "SVC": {
      "currencyName": "Salvadoran Colón",
      "id": "SVC"
    },
    "ZMK": {
      "currencyName": "Old Zambian Kwacha",
      "id": "ZMK"
    },
    "XAG": {
      "currencyName": "Silver (troy ounce)",
      "id": "XAG"
    },
    "ZWL": {
      "currencyName": "Zimbabwean Dollar",
      "id": "ZWL"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `*ngFor` can handle this json object.

Comment: I need the steps. that i knew it can be looped over when i will reach the last parent object. How to extract the value for this object

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys` to achieve this

```
var json = {
  "results": {
    "ALL": {
      "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
      "currencySymbol": "Lek",
      "id": "ALL"
    },
    "XCD": {
      "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "XCD"
    }
  }
]

const res = Object.keys(json.results).map(key => ({currencyName: json.results[key].currencyName,id: json.results[key].id}))

console.log(res)
```

```js
var json = {
  "results": {
    "ALL": {
      "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
      "currencySymbol": "Lek",
      "id": "ALL"
    },
    "XCD": {
      "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "XCD"
    },
    "EUR": {
      "currencyName": "Euro",
      "currencySymbol": "€",
      "id": "EUR"
    },
    "BBD": {
      "currencyName": "Barbadian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "BBD"
    },
    "BTN": {
      "currencyName": "Bhutanese Ngultrum",
      "id": "BTN"
    },
    "BND": {
      "currencyName": "Brunei Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "BND"
    },
    "XAF": {
      "currencyName": "Central African CFA Franc",
      "id": "XAF"
    },
    "CUP": {
      "currencyName": "Cuban Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "CUP"
    },
    "USD": {
      "currencyName": "United States Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "USD"
    },
    "FKP": {
      "currencyName": "Falkland Islands Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "FKP"
    },
    "GIP": {
      "currencyName": "Gibraltar Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "GIP"
    },
    "HUF": {
      "currencyName": "Hungarian Forint",
      "currencySymbol": "Ft",
      "id": "HUF"
    },
    "IRR": {
      "currencyName": "Iranian Rial",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "IRR"
    },
    "JMD": {
      "currencyName": "Jamaican Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "J$",
      "id": "JMD"
    },
    "AUD": {
      "currencyName": "Australian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "AUD"
    },
    "LAK": {
      "currencyName": "Lao Kip",
      "currencySymbol": "₭",
      "id": "LAK"
    },
    "LYD": {
      "currencyName": "Libyan Dinar",
      "id": "LYD"
    },
    "MKD": {
      "currencyName": "Macedonian Denar",
      "currencySymbol": "ден",
      "id": "MKD"
    },
    "XOF": {
      "currencyName": "West African CFA Franc",
      "id": "XOF"
    },
    "NZD": {
      "currencyName": "New Zealand Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "NZD"
    },
    "OMR": {
      "currencyName": "Omani Rial",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "OMR"
    },
    "PGK": {
      "currencyName": "Papua New Guinean Kina",
      "id": "PGK"
    },
    "RWF": {
      "currencyName": "Rwandan Franc",
      "id": "RWF"
    },
    "WST": {
      "currencyName": "Samoan Tala",
      "id": "WST"
    },
    "RSD": {
      "currencyName": "Serbian Dinar",
      "currencySymbol": "Дин.",
      "id": "RSD"
    },
    "SEK": {
      "currencyName": "Swedish Krona",
      "currencySymbol": "kr",
      "id": "SEK"
    },
    "TZS": {
      "currencyName": "Tanzanian Shilling",
      "currencySymbol": "TSh",
      "id": "TZS"
    },
    "AMD": {
      "currencyName": "Armenian Dram",
      "id": "AMD"
    },
    "BSD": {
      "currencyName": "Bahamian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "BSD"
    },
    "BAM": {
      "currencyName": "Bosnia And Herzegovina Konvertibilna Marka",
      "currencySymbol": "KM",
      "id": "BAM"
    },
    "CVE": {
      "currencyName": "Cape Verdean Escudo",
      "id": "CVE"
    },
    "CNY": {
      "currencyName": "Chinese Yuan",
      "currencySymbol": "¥",
      "id": "CNY"
    },
    "CRC": {
      "currencyName": "Costa Rican Colon",
      "currencySymbol": "₡",
      "id": "CRC"
    },
    "CZK": {
      "currencyName": "Czech Koruna",
      "currencySymbol": "Kč",
      "id": "CZK"
    },
    "ERN": {
      "currencyName": "Eritrean Nakfa",
      "id": "ERN"
    },
    "GEL": {
      "currencyName": "Georgian Lari",
      "id": "GEL"
    },
    "HTG": {
      "currencyName": "Haitian Gourde",
      "id": "HTG"
    },
    "INR": {
      "currencyName": "Indian Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₹",
      "id": "INR"
    },
    "JOD": {
      "currencyName": "Jordanian Dinar",
      "id": "JOD"
    },
    "KRW": {
      "currencyName": "South Korean Won",
      "currencySymbol": "₩",
      "id": "KRW"
    },
    "LBP": {
      "currencyName": "Lebanese Lira",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "LBP"
    },
    "MWK": {
      "currencyName": "Malawian Kwacha",
      "id": "MWK"
    },
    "MRO": {
      "currencyName": "Mauritanian Ouguiya",
      "id": "MRO"
    },
    "MZN": {
      "currencyName": "Mozambican Metical",
      "id": "MZN"
    },
    "ANG": {
      "currencyName": "Netherlands Antillean Gulden",
      "currencySymbol": "ƒ",
      "id": "ANG"
    },
    "PEN": {
      "currencyName": "Peruvian Nuevo Sol",
      "currencySymbol": "S/.",
      "id": "PEN"
    },
    "QAR": {
      "currencyName": "Qatari Riyal",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "QAR"
    },
    "STD": {
      "currencyName": "Sao Tome And Principe Dobra",
      "id": "STD"
    },
    "SLL": {
      "currencyName": "Sierra Leonean Leone",
      "id": "SLL"
    },
    "SOS": {
      "currencyName": "Somali Shilling",
      "currencySymbol": "S",
      "id": "SOS"
    },
    "SDG": {
      "currencyName": "Sudanese Pound",
      "id": "SDG"
    },
    "SYP": {
      "currencyName": "Syrian Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "SYP"
    },
    "AOA": {
      "currencyName": "Angolan Kwanza",
      "id": "AOA"
    },
    "AWG": {
      "currencyName": "Aruban Florin",
      "currencySymbol": "ƒ",
      "id": "AWG"
    },
    "BHD": {
      "currencyName": "Bahraini Dinar",
      "id": "BHD"
    },
    "BZD": {
      "currencyName": "Belize Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "BZ$",
      "id": "BZD"
    },
    "BWP": {
      "currencyName": "Botswana Pula",
      "currencySymbol": "P",
      "id": "BWP"
    },
    "BIF": {
      "currencyName": "Burundi Franc",
      "id": "BIF"
    },
    "KYD": {
      "currencyName": "Cayman Islands Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "KYD"
    },
    "COP": {
      "currencyName": "Colombian Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "COP"
    },
    "DKK": {
      "currencyName": "Danish Krone",
      "currencySymbol": "kr",
      "id": "DKK"
    },
    "GTQ": {
      "currencyName": "Guatemalan Quetzal",
      "currencySymbol": "Q",
      "id": "GTQ"
    },
    "HNL": {
      "currencyName": "Honduran Lempira",
      "currencySymbol": "L",
      "id": "HNL"
    },
    "IDR": {
      "currencyName": "Indonesian Rupiah",
      "currencySymbol": "Rp",
      "id": "IDR"
    },
    "ILS": {
      "currencyName": "Israeli New Sheqel",
      "currencySymbol": "₪",
      "id": "ILS"
    },
    "KZT": {
      "currencyName": "Kazakhstani Tenge",
      "currencySymbol": "лв",
      "id": "KZT"
    },
    "KWD": {
      "currencyName": "Kuwaiti Dinar",
      "id": "KWD"
    },
    "LSL": {
      "currencyName": "Lesotho Loti",
      "id": "LSL"
    },
    "MYR": {
      "currencyName": "Malaysian Ringgit",
      "currencySymbol": "RM",
      "id": "MYR"
    },
    "MUR": {
      "currencyName": "Mauritian Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "MUR"
    },
    "MNT": {
      "currencyName": "Mongolian Tugrik",
      "currencySymbol": "₮",
      "id": "MNT"
    },
    "MMK": {
      "currencyName": "Myanma Kyat",
      "id": "MMK"
    },
    "NGN": {
      "currencyName": "Nigerian Naira",
      "currencySymbol": "₦",
      "id": "NGN"
    },
    "PAB": {
      "currencyName": "Panamanian Balboa",
      "currencySymbol": "B/.",
      "id": "PAB"
    },
    "PHP": {
      "currencyName": "Philippine Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "₱",
      "id": "PHP"
    },
    "RON": {
      "currencyName": "Romanian Leu",
      "currencySymbol": "lei",
      "id": "RON"
    },
    "SAR": {
      "currencyName": "Saudi Riyal",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "SAR"
    },
    "SGD": {
      "currencyName": "Singapore Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "SGD"
    },
    "ZAR": {
      "currencyName": "South African Rand",
      "currencySymbol": "R",
      "id": "ZAR"
    },
    "SRD": {
      "currencyName": "Surinamese Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "SRD"
    },
    "TWD": {
      "currencyName": "New Taiwan Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "NT$",
      "id": "TWD"
    },
    "TOP": {
      "currencyName": "Paanga",
      "id": "TOP"
    },
    "VEF": {
      "currencyName": "Venezuelan Bolivar",
      "id": "VEF"
    },
    "DZD": {
      "currencyName": "Algerian Dinar",
      "id": "DZD"
    },
    "ARS": {
      "currencyName": "Argentine Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "ARS"
    },
    "AZN": {
      "currencyName": "Azerbaijani Manat",
      "currencySymbol": "ман",
      "id": "AZN"
    },
    "BYR": {
      "currencyName": "Belarusian Ruble",
      "currencySymbol": "p.",
      "id": "BYR"
    },
    "BOB": {
      "currencyName": "Bolivian Boliviano",
      "currencySymbol": "$b",
      "id": "BOB"
    },
    "BGN": {
      "currencyName": "Bulgarian Lev",
      "currencySymbol": "лв",
      "id": "BGN"
    },
    "CAD": {
      "currencyName": "Canadian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "CAD"
    },
    "CLP": {
      "currencyName": "Chilean Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "CLP"
    },
    "CDF": {
      "currencyName": "Congolese Franc",
      "id": "CDF"
    },
    "DOP": {
      "currencyName": "Dominican Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "RD$",
      "id": "DOP"
    },
    "FJD": {
      "currencyName": "Fijian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "FJD"
    },
    "GMD": {
      "currencyName": "Gambian Dalasi",
      "id": "GMD"
    },
    "GYD": {
      "currencyName": "Guyanese Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "GYD"
    },
    "ISK": {
      "currencyName": "Icelandic Króna",
      "currencySymbol": "kr",
      "id": "ISK"
    },
    "IQD": {
      "currencyName": "Iraqi Dinar",
      "id": "IQD"
    },
    "JPY": {
      "currencyName": "Japanese Yen",
      "currencySymbol": "¥",
      "id": "JPY"
    },
    "KPW": {
      "currencyName": "North Korean Won",
      "currencySymbol": "₩",
      "id": "KPW"
    },
    "LVL": {
      "currencyName": "Latvian Lats",
      "currencySymbol": "Ls",
      "id": "LVL"
    },
    "CHF": {
      "currencyName": "Swiss Franc",
      "currencySymbol": "Fr.",
      "id": "CHF"
    },
    "MGA": {
      "currencyName": "Malagasy Ariary",
      "id": "MGA"
    },
    "MDL": {
      "currencyName": "Moldovan Leu",
      "id": "MDL"
    },
    "MAD": {
      "currencyName": "Moroccan Dirham",
      "id": "MAD"
    },
    "NPR": {
      "currencyName": "Nepalese Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "NPR"
    },
    "NIO": {
      "currencyName": "Nicaraguan Cordoba",
      "currencySymbol": "C$",
      "id": "NIO"
    },
    "PKR": {
      "currencyName": "Pakistani Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "PKR"
    },
    "PYG": {
      "currencyName": "Paraguayan Guarani",
      "currencySymbol": "Gs",
      "id": "PYG"
    },
    "SHP": {
      "currencyName": "Saint Helena Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "SHP"
    },
    "SCR": {
      "currencyName": "Seychellois Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "SCR"
    },
    "SBD": {
      "currencyName": "Solomon Islands Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "SBD"
    },
    "LKR": {
      "currencyName": "Sri Lankan Rupee",
      "currencySymbol": "₨",
      "id": "LKR"
    },
    "THB": {
      "currencyName": "Thai Baht",
      "currencySymbol": "฿",
      "id": "THB"
    },
    "TRY": {
      "currencyName": "Turkish New Lira",
      "id": "TRY"
    },
    "AED": {
      "currencyName": "UAE Dirham",
      "id": "AED"
    },
    "VUV": {
      "currencyName": "Vanuatu Vatu",
      "id": "VUV"
    },
    "YER": {
      "currencyName": "Yemeni Rial",
      "currencySymbol": "﷼",
      "id": "YER"
    },
    "AFN": {
      "currencyName": "Afghan Afghani",
      "currencySymbol": "؋",
      "id": "AFN"
    },
    "BDT": {
      "currencyName": "Bangladeshi Taka",
      "id": "BDT"
    },
    "BRL": {
      "currencyName": "Brazilian Real",
      "currencySymbol": "R$",
      "id": "BRL"
    },
    "KHR": {
      "currencyName": "Cambodian Riel",
      "currencySymbol": "៛",
      "id": "KHR"
    },
    "KMF": {
      "currencyName": "Comorian Franc",
      "id": "KMF"
    },
    "HRK": {
      "currencyName": "Croatian Kuna",
      "currencySymbol": "kn",
      "id": "HRK"
    },
    "DJF": {
      "currencyName": "Djiboutian Franc",
      "id": "DJF"
    },
    "EGP": {
      "currencyName": "Egyptian Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "EGP"
    },
    "ETB": {
      "currencyName": "Ethiopian Birr",
      "id": "ETB"
    },
    "XPF": {
      "currencyName": "CFP Franc",
      "id": "XPF"
    },
    "GHS": {
      "currencyName": "Ghanaian Cedi",
      "id": "GHS"
    },
    "GNF": {
      "currencyName": "Guinean Franc",
      "id": "GNF"
    },
    "HKD": {
      "currencyName": "Hong Kong Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "HKD"
    },
    "XDR": {
      "currencyName": "Special Drawing Rights",
      "id": "XDR"
    },
    "KES": {
      "currencyName": "Kenyan Shilling",
      "currencySymbol": "KSh",
      "id": "KES"
    },
    "KGS": {
      "currencyName": "Kyrgyzstani Som",
      "currencySymbol": "лв",
      "id": "KGS"
    },
    "LRD": {
      "currencyName": "Liberian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "LRD"
    },
    "MOP": {
      "currencyName": "Macanese Pataca",
      "id": "MOP"
    },
    "MVR": {
      "currencyName": "Maldivian Rufiyaa",
      "id": "MVR"
    },
    "MXN": {
      "currencyName": "Mexican Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "MXN"
    },
    "NAD": {
      "currencyName": "Namibian Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "NAD"
    },
    "NOK": {
      "currencyName": "Norwegian Krone",
      "currencySymbol": "kr",
      "id": "NOK"
    },
    "PLN": {
      "currencyName": "Polish Zloty",
      "currencySymbol": "zł",
      "id": "PLN"
    },
    "RUB": {
      "currencyName": "Russian Ruble",
      "currencySymbol": "руб",
      "id": "RUB"
    },
    "SZL": {
      "currencyName": "Swazi Lilangeni",
      "id": "SZL"
    },
    "TJS": {
      "currencyName": "Tajikistani Somoni",
      "id": "TJS"
    },
    "TTD": {
      "currencyName": "Trinidad and Tobago Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "TT$",
      "id": "TTD"
    },
    "UGX": {
      "currencyName": "Ugandan Shilling",
      "currencySymbol": "USh",
      "id": "UGX"
    },
    "UYU": {
      "currencyName": "Uruguayan Peso",
      "currencySymbol": "$U",
      "id": "UYU"
    },
    "VND": {
      "currencyName": "Vietnamese Dong",
      "currencySymbol": "₫",
      "id": "VND"
    },
    "TND": {
      "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar",
      "id": "TND"
    },
    "UAH": {
      "currencyName": "Ukrainian Hryvnia",
      "currencySymbol": "₴",
      "id": "UAH"
    },
    "UZS": {
      "currencyName": "Uzbekistani Som",
      "currencySymbol": "лв",
      "id": "UZS"
    },
    "TMT": {
      "currencyName": "Turkmenistan Manat",
      "id": "TMT"
    },
    "GBP": {
      "currencyName": "British Pound",
      "currencySymbol": "£",
      "id": "GBP"
    },
    "ZMW": {
      "currencyName": "Zambian Kwacha",
      "id": "ZMW"
    },
    "BTC": {
      "currencyName": "Bitcoin",
      "currencySymbol": "BTC",
      "id": "BTC"
    },
    "BYN": {
      "currencyName": "New Belarusian Ruble",
      "currencySymbol": "p.",
      "id": "BYN"
    },
    "BMD": {
      "currencyName": "Bermudan Dollar",
      "id": "BMD"
    },
    "GGP": {
      "currencyName": "Guernsey Pound",
      "id": "GGP"
    },
    "CLF": {
      "currencyName": "Chilean Unit Of Account",
      "id": "CLF"
    },
    "CUC": {
      "currencyName": "Cuban Convertible Peso",
      "id": "CUC"
    },
    "IMP": {
      "currencyName": "Manx pound",
      "id": "IMP"
    },
    "JEP": {
      "currencyName": "Jersey Pound",
      "id": "JEP"
    },
    "SVC": {
      "currencyName": "Salvadoran Colón",
      "id": "SVC"
    },
    "ZMK": {
      "currencyName": "Old Zambian Kwacha",
      "id": "ZMK"
    },
    "XAG": {
      "currencyName": "Silver (troy ounce)",
      "id": "XAG"
    },
    "ZWL": {
      "currencyName": "Zimbabwean Dollar",
      "id": "ZWL"
    }
  }
}

// console.log(json)

const res = Object.keys(json.results).map(key => ({currencyName: json.results[key].currencyName,id: json.results[key].id}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. but this is not working for ANGULAR

Comment: Cannot find name 'json'. Did you mean 'JSON'?ts(2552)
lib.es5.d.ts(1079, 13): 'JSON' is declared here.

Comment: `json` is just the variable I used here for the sake of the example.  You will have to replace it with what ever variable you have the result in. Also if you are planning to create a list in angular you could use `*ngFor` for looping through. the resulting list.

Comment: I have also elaborated the example , hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. yes. it's showing the response but I think it's not the ideal way(let's take an example if there are more than 20 keys what to do then?) is it ideal to just initialize each one of the keys?

Comment: No, you won't be initialising any data. Data might be coming form an end point you might be calling using an http service. You just have to use `Object.keys` to extract the data from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to extract the result from the response and then the **spread operator** to get all keys of each item without even knowing their names. Finally, you can iterate over the result array and display each item id and currencyName. This array can be accessed in an Angular template where you can use *ngFor to display all items.

```
const jsonResponse = {
  "results": {
    "ALL": {
      "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
      "currencySymbol": "Lek",
      "id": "ALL"
    },
    "XCD": {
      "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "XCD"
    },
    "EUR": {
      "currencyName": "Euro",
      "currencySymbol": "€",
      "id": "EUR"
    },
  }
}

const itemsArray = Object.keys(jsonResponse.results).map((key) => ({...jsonResponse.results[key]}))

itemsArray.forEach((item) => console.log(item.id, item.currencyName));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but can anyone help me fetch data with the help of the interface? like making an interface for the coming response and then do the same thing(consoling or dumping it into the UI).

Comment: ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.getAllCurrency()
    .subscribe(data => {
      const itemsArray = Object.keys(data.results).map((key) => ({...data.results[key]}))

      itemsArray.forEach((item) => console.log(item.id, item.currencyName));
      console.log(data.results)
    })
  }

Comment: error:-               Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'.